# Files.isHidden vs File#isHidden

Tags: java, nio

In my unit test, I wrote the following code:

```
assertTrue(Files.isHidden(path));
```

The test fails at that line.

In Windows file explorer, I checked that the file exists and is hidden.
After trying the following alternatives, I'm looking for an explanation.

```
path.toFile().isHidden(); // returns true
Files.getAttribute(path, "dos:hidden", LinkOption.NOFOLLOW_LINKS); // returns true
Files.isHidden(path); // returns false
```

Running Windows & Oracle JDK v1.8.0-ea.

Ideas, anyone?

**UPDATE:**

I don't know what happened, but the test now succeeds using any of the 3 lines including `Files.isHidden(path);`! It could be the IDE or something.. (IntelliJ 12.1.4 CE on Windows 8 64bit).

I'm still interested in the difference between these methods, specifically where one might be better than the other.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your behavior. All 3 return `true` for me.

Comment: How did you make your file hidden? I went into `Properties` and checked the `hidden` checkbox.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis what's your OS and Java version? do you think it has something to do with ea?
I made hidden using the code: Files.setAttribute(path, "dos:hidden", true, NOFOLLOW_LINKS);

Comment: I'm on Windows 7, `Java 1.7.0-b147`

Comment: Setting it programatically also worked for me...

Comment: @AnasH.Sulaiman What is your version of Windows ? It's not mentioned in the question.

Comment: @Marc-Andre Windows 8